# Declaring a boolean in JavaScript using just var

Tags: javascript, boolean

If I declare a JavaScript boolean variable like this:

```
var IsLoggedIn;
```

And then initialize it with either `true` or `1`, is that safe?  Or will initializing it with `1` make the variable a number?

Comment: It really does depend on what you mean by "safe", there is no "safe" in javascript.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Types are dependent to your initialization:

```
var IsLoggedIn1 = "true"; //string
var IsLoggedIn2 = 1; //integer
var IsLoggedIn3 = true; //bool
```

But take a look at this example:

```
var IsLoggedIn1 = "true"; //string
IsLoggedIn1 = true; //now your variable is a boolean
```

Your variables' type depends on the assigned value in JavaScript.

Comment: what if i directly declares boolean variable as boolean. is that make any performance improvment

Answer (score 20):

No it is not safe. You could later do var `IsLoggedIn = "Foo";` and JavaScript will not throw an error.

It is possible to do

```
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean(false);
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean(true);
```

You can also pass the non boolean variable into the `new Boolean()` and it will make IsLoggedIn boolean.

```
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean(0); // false
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean(NaN); // false
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean("Foo"); // true
var IsLoggedIn = new Boolean(1); // true
```

Comment: Don't use new Boolean(); IsLoggedIn will evaluate to true in all of those situations (yes, new Boolean(false) is true).

Comment: @Miles: new Boolean(false) is false not true

Comment: @jan: `if (new Boolean(false)) alert ('wat')` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8695363

Comment: @Miles Incredible, as `(new Boolean(false)).toString()) === "false"`, thanks for the link

Answer (score 12):

As this [very useful tutorial](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) says:

```
var age = 0;

// bad
var hasAge = new Boolean(age);

// good
var hasAge = Boolean(age);

// good
var hasAge = !!age;
```

Comment: probably no real explanation. no one wants to comb through a tutorial you could specify in a tl;dr in your post

Answer (score 7):

If you want `IsLoggedIn` to be treated as a boolean you should initialize as follows:

```
var IsLoggedIn=true;
```

If you initialize it with `var IsLoggedIn=1;` then it will be treated as an integer.

However at any time the variable `IsLoggedIn` could refer to a different data type:

```
 IsLoggedIn="Hello World";
```

This will not cause an error.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use and test uninitialized variables at least for their 'definedness'. 
Like this:

```
var iAmNotDefined;
alert(!iAmNotDefined); //true
//or
alert(!!iAmNotDefined); //false
```

Furthermore, there are many possibilites: if you're not interested in exact types use the '==' operator (or ![variable] / !![variable]) for comparison (that is what Douglas Crockford calls 'truthy' or 'falsy' I think). In that case assigning true or 1 or '1' to the unitialized variable always returns true when asked. Otherwise [if you need type safe comparison] use '===' for comparison.

```
var thisMayBeTrue;

thisMayBeTrue = 1;
alert(thisMayBeTrue == true); //=> true
alert(!!thisMayBeTrue); //=> true
alert(thisMayBeTrue === true); //=> false

thisMayBeTrue = '1';
alert(thisMayBeTrue == true); //=> true 
alert(!!thisMayBeTrue); //=> true
alert(thisMayBeTrue === true); //=> false
// so, in this case, using == or !! '1' is implicitly 
// converted to 1 and 1 is implicitly converted to true)

thisMayBeTrue = true;
alert(thisMayBeTrue == true); //=> true
alert(!!thisMayBeTrue); //=> true
alert(thisMayBeTrue === true); //=> true

thisMayBeTrue = 'true';
alert(thisMayBeTrue == true); //=> false
alert(!!thisMayBeTrue); //=> true
alert(thisMayBeTrue === true); //=> false
// so, here's no implicit conversion of the string 'true'
// it's also a demonstration of the fact that the 
// ! or !! operator tests the 'definedness' of a variable.
```

PS: you can't test 'definedness' for nonexisting variables though. So:

```
alert(!!HelloWorld);
```

gives a reference Error ('HelloWorld is not defined')

(is there a better word for 'definedness'? Pardon my dutch anyway;~)

Comment: You might like to retry your string cases with an empty string `thisMayBeTrue = '';` - you won't get the same results since an empty string is falsy. _"PS: you can't test 'definedness' for nonexisting variables though"_ - Sure you can: `typeof HellowWorld === 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in Javascript don't have a type. Non-zero, non-null, non-empty and `true` are "true". Zero, null, undefined, empty string and `false` are "false".

There's a Boolean type though, as are literals `true` and `false`.

Comment: JS _variables_ don't have a type in the sense that you can't declare a variable that will only hold integers or strings (as happens in some other languages), but the particular _value_ held by the variable at any given time will always have a type. And the type matters as can be shown with a simple example like `2 + 2` vs `"2" + 2`. See also the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
var MyNamespace = {
    convertToBoolean: function (value) {
        //VALIDATE INPUT
        if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value === null) return false;

        //DETERMINE BOOLEAN VALUE FROM STRING
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'true':
                case 'yes':
                case '1':
                    return true;
                case 'false':
                case 'no':
                case '0':
                    return false;
            }
        }

        //RETURN DEFAULT HANDLER
        return Boolean(value);
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
MyNamespace.convertToBoolean('true') //true
MyNamespace.convertToBoolean('no') //false
MyNamespace.convertToBoolean('1') //true
MyNamespace.convertToBoolean(0) //false
```

I have not tested it for performance, but converting from type to type should not happen too often otherwise you open your app up to instability big time!

Comment: Why the down vote? Please explain so we can all benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The variable will become what ever type you assign it.  Initially it is `undefined`.  If you assign it `'true'` it will become a string, if you assign it `true` it will become a boolean, if you assign it `1` it will become a number.  Subsequent assignments may change the type of the variable later.