# Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, language-design

From [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Boolean_Default) on JavaScript types comes this snippet of code describing the behavior of strings when converted to booleans (that topic is not related to this question, but it's just where I found the code):

```
!"" // true
!"hello" // false
!"true" // false
!new Boolean(false) // false
```

I get the first three examples, but I don't get the last example, because:

```
new Boolean(false) == false //true
!false // true
```

So I would assume:

```
!new Boolean(false) // true
```

But instead:

```
!new Boolean(false) // false, mind = blown
```

What is this I don't even...

Is it because:

```
new Boolean(false) === false // false
```

If so, what purpose does this serve?

Comment: +1 for deeply analysed question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`new Boolean(false)` returns an **object**. All objects (except `document.all` in browsers) are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

As a result, `!` of any object will always be `false`.

---

To prove it to yourself, you can run this in your JavaScript console:

```js
(typeof new Boolean(false)) // "object"
```

Also, you can use the strict equality operator `===` to confirm that `new Boolean(false)` isn’t really `false`:

```js
new Boolean(false) === false // false
```

Incidentally, calling the `Boolean` function as a function—without the `new`—actually does return a primitive:

```js
!Boolean(false) // true
(typeof Boolean(false)) // "boolean"
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `new Boolean` returns an object [as stated here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.6.2.1).

The `!` is defined [as follows](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9):

> 11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator ( `!` )
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `!` *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. Let *oldValue* be `ToBoolean(GetValue(expr))`.
> 3. If *oldValue* is `true`, return `false`.
> 4. Return `true`.

[and](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2):

> 9.2 ToBoolean
>
> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:
>
> Table 11 — ToBoolean Conversions
>
> Argument Type - Result
>
> ...
>
> Object - `true`

So, it is an object, thus `ToBoolean` returns `true`, hence `!` returns `false`.

Comment: Current specification: [`Boolean`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-boolean-constructor-boolean-value), [ordinary object](//tc39.es/ecma262/#ordinary-object), [ToBoolean](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toboolean). If this answer is to be edited, it is probably necessary to explain that [OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor) creates an ordinary object and that [NewTarget](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NewTarget) is a production that, in the case of `Boolean(`…`)`, evaluates to `undefined`, but not in the case of `new Boolean(`…`)`.