# Javascript Boolean type

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript)

```
var b = new Boolean(null);


alert(b instanceof Boolean);

 if(b) {
    alert('cv');
    alert(b.toString());
 }
```

Why if code block is executed? Is b supposed to be a boolean type and evaluated as false?

Please explain thanks

Comment: new Boolean, new Number and new String should never be used in practical javascript. It's kinda like you wouldn't use `==` to compare strings in java, you wouldn't use `new String` in javascript because `new String("asd") == new String("asd") //false` but `"asd" == "asd" //true` same for new Boolean and new Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `object`s are truthy, except `null`. Therefore, even if you write `new Boolean(false)` specifically, it will still be truthy.

This is why you never write `new Boolean`. To cast to a boolean, just use `!!`

Answer (score 2):

The code block executes, because the object exists and is not undefined although it has no value currently. The point of the Boolean object in javascript is to convert non-boolean objects to the "true" or "false" value.

if you have

```
if( b.valueOf() );
```

that will evaluate the actual value of the object.