# Why is (condition == !condition) true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Exactly why does the condition here evaluate to true?

```
var condition = new Boolean(false);
if (condition == !condition)
    alert("The more you know...");
```

Comment: anyone noticed `condition === !condition` returning `false`.

Comment: The `==` operator performs type coercion when comparing different types. You're comparing an object to a boolean. Read the algorithm used to coerce the types to matching types here: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Comment: This should help settling things down: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/zKQ77/3/

Comment: @CrazyTrain acdcjunior Well said.  Thank you so much for the link and fiddle.

Comment: @acdcjunior: I don't get it, your JSFiddle just shows me the output. The question isn't *what* the output is, but *why*.

Comment: @Mehrdad true (at least this one is for sure :), that's why I didn't post is as an answer. It should help because there is an assertion war going on, and that may show what the browser actually does.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Break it down:

```
var condition = new Boolean(false);
```

This is actually an object, and `condition.valueOf() === false`

`!{}` evaluates to false since `{}` is true (explained http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)

So the check is `condition.valueOf() == false`, which is true

Comment: @Blender `new Boolean(false).valueOf()` is false

Comment: `.valueOf()` returns the underlying primitive, which isn't an object. `(new Boolean(false)) === false`.

Comment: From docs `The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed Boolean object is set to ToBoolean(value).` . So that explains why `condition` that evaluates to false..

Comment: @sissonb: All objects are truthy, just like `'foo' == true` is false, but `'foo'` is truthy.

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8695363/924943) seems similar.

Comment: `condition` evaluates to `condition.valueOf`  And `!condition` is evaluated to a boolean value.. So  `false == false`

Comment: @Nirk: So you're saying `==` calls `valueOf` on objects before comparing them?

Comment: @Nirk: Never mind, just confirmed it myself.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not really: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @Blender: Interesting, it seems to do so on Chrome. At least when I created a member named `valueOf`, I could alter its behavior.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `.valueOf()` is called eventually for objects, but that's not the whole algorithm.

Comment: @Mehrdad: So in this case, after the not operator is applied on `condition`, you'll actually compare `condition == false`, which is `condition == 0`, which is `false == 0`, and finally `0 == 0`, which is `true`.

Answer (score 23):

You're comparing an object (LHS) to the boolean `false` (RHS).

```
[object Boolean] == false
```

The `==` operator performs type coercion according to the *Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm* defined by ECMAScript. 11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm

Relevant to your code is the following point of that algorithm *(where x is the LHS and y is the RHS)*.

> **7)** If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Notice that it actually first attempts to convert the boolean to a number. The `false` boolean converts to the number `0`, so now we have this:

```
[object Boolean] == 0
```

As you can see, it recursively enters the same algorithm because of the `==`. So now we're comparing an object to a number and so the following point applies:

> **9)** If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

So here it's now attempting to coerce the object to its primitive value. From *9.1 ToPrimitive*, when called on an Object:

> **Object**   Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

So you can see that it wants the `[[DefaultValue]]` of the object. That brings us to *8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]]*, where it expects a "hint". Because it received no "hint", it behaves as though the hint was "Number".

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number,...

And so that brings us to the following behavior:

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with hint Number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> 2. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>    a. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>
>    b. If val is a primitive value, return val.

And so it calls the `.valueOf()` method on the object, bringing us to *15.6.4.3 Boolean.prototype.valueOf ( )*

> 1. Let B be the this value.
> 2. If Type(B) is Boolean, then let b be B.
> 3. Else if Type(B) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal property of B is "Boolean", then let b be the value of the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of B.
> 4. Else throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. Return b.

And so you can see from step 3 that it will return the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` of the object. That brings us to *15.6.2.1 new Boolean (value)*

> The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed Boolean object is set to ToBoolean(value).

And so you can see that you'll finally get the `ToBoolean` value of the value you originally passed to the constructor, which was `false`. Its `ToBoolean` value is obviously `false`, so now your comparison is this:

```
false == 0
```

Since the types still don't match, it'll go to point 6 in the original algorithm:

> **6)** If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

And so it now wants to convert the boolean `false` to a number. This is similar to what was done above. The value `false` converts to the value `0`, so now we have:

```
0 == 0
```

And finally we have a type matched comparison, and so it behaves the same as its strict `===` counterpart, by comparing values. And clearly, `0` does equal `0`, so we get `true`.

---

*Moral of the story... this is what you get when you ask "why" in JavaScript.*

Comment: This should be the minimal answer to why questions :D

Comment: We're crazy, we follow those steps and cross-references and write these answers... Three of us this time!

Answer (score 7):

It really helps just to read the spec where this is logically laid out, see

Start with:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);
var y = !x;
```

Then

```
y = false;
```

Because a boolean object is **not** considered a boolean but an everday object, `ToBoolean(x)` [evaluates to `true`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) and the [`!true` evaluates to `false`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9)

[The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Round 1:  **step 7**

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x ==
>   ToNumber(y).

```
y = 0; //ToNumber(false) is 0
```

Round 2:  **step 9**

> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return
>   the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

```
x = false //Basically ends up calling x.valueOf()
```

Round 3: **Step 6**

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x)
>   == y.

```
x = 0; //ToNumber(false) is 0
```

Finally: **Step 1**

> If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then

**Step 1 C**

> If Type(x) is Number, then

**Step 1 C iii**

> If x is the same Number value as y, return true.

Comment: @bfavaretto nope, type(x) *is* object, whereas y was already converted to a number in first round

Comment: @bfavaretto oops yea you're right :D

Comment: And I don't see why you got two downvotes!

Comment: Why the $#!t would this get two down votes? It's right out of the spec for crying out loud!

Comment: yeah I don't know what to say, the edits have mostly just added bolding too, so the answer was not in downvotable state at any point

Comment: Why actually did you start with `var y = false`, not `true`?

Comment: @zerkms that was explained right below... because it was not part of the algorithm and didn't find nicely in the rounds format. The most relevant insight about that is that a boolean object is not considered a boolean in anyway.

Comment: @Esailija: I see. Probably you could add `!x` to explain that additionally

Comment: @zerkms ok done that now

Answer (score 4):

One thing I learned from [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) is, forget intuition, and follow the steps.

As objects are truthy, their negation is `false`, so what goes into the algorithm is:

```
Boolean(false) == false
```

If you go step by step, you get:

```
Boolean(false) == 0  // Step 7
false == 0           // Step 9
0 == 0               // Step 6
true
```

Comment: Forget intuition... best advice one could possibly give.