# Why doesn't this if statement work as expected?

Tags: javascript

I came across with something like this today.(I thought that it
would alert goodbye)

```
x = new Boolean(false);

if (x) {
  alert('hello');
}else{
    alert('goodbye');
}
```

I thought that was something like this(Which alerts goodbye):

```
x = false;

if (x) {
  alert('hello');
}else{
    alert('goodbye');
}
```

I don't I understand how it works.

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an instance of the [Boolean function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), not a boolean primitive.

`true` and `false` in javascript are *boolean primitives*.  When you use them with boolean operators, they behave as you would expect.  For example `true || false` is `true` and `true && false` is `false`.

On the other hand, `Boolean` is a special function which can convert other data types into boolean's (among other things).  When you call `new Boolean(false)`, you're creating a `Boolean` object which *contains* the boolean primitive `false`.  That's the critical distinction in this case.

In short,

- `if(new Boolean())` uses javascript's truthy value rules.  It is an object which is not null, so it's "true".
- `if(false)` is a boolean primitive and actually checks for true/false.

Answer (score 3):

You should look up the "truthy - falsy" properties of javascript. Here is an [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). In the first case `x` is true, because it is a non-null and non-undefined object, hence it is **truthy**. In the second, `x` is a `boolean` type of `false`, which is **falsy**.

Some things to remember from the article:

> The following values are *falsy*:

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

> Everything else is *truthy*!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `typeof x` you realize x is an object. Object are always true.

Most values
convert to true with the exception of the following, which convert to false:

- The empty string ""
- null
- undefined
- The number 0
- The number NaN
- The Boolean false

Answer (score 2):

`new Boolean(false)` returns an object which is not null. Non-null objects are always `true`.
*[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8695363/643482)*