# differences between Boolean answers in javascript

Tags: javascript

why these two code has different answers:

code 1 answer is false
code 2 answer is true

### code 1

```
var x = Boolean (false);
if (x) 
{
      console.log (true);
}
else 
{
      console.log (false);
}
// answer is false
```

### code2

```
var x = new Boolean (false);
if (x)
{
     console.log (true);
}
else 
{
     console.log (false);
}

//answer is true
```

Comment: Did you log the `x` to console in both the codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block omits the "new" keyword, x is assigned the value of Boolean(expr), which is a function that converts a non-boolean value to a boolean one.

The second block creates a Boolean object, the if conditional returns true because x is not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean
>   object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a
>   conditional statement.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

The global function Boolean() can be used for type casting when called without new, eg

```
var foo = Boolean(param); // equivalent to `var foo = !!param`
```

When called with new, a wrapper object will be created additionally, which means that you can assign arbitrary properties to the object:

```
var foo = new Boolean(param); // equivalent to `var foo = Object(Boolean(param));`
console.log(foo === true) // true, because object - true
foo.prop1 = 'test';
```