# Logical NOT on Boolean Object always return false in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why [logical not operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator) in javascript returns different result between [Boolean value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-boolean-value) and [Boolean object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-boolean-object)? Consider the following example.

```
!true  // false
!false // true

!(new Boolean(true))  // false
!(new Boolean(false)) // false
```

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator), it says that the value being evaluated converted `ToBoolean`. [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) will return true if the argument is an Object, and return as is if the argument is a Boolean.

Digging further, ToBoolean also being used in other places like if statement and conditional operator, consider the following example:

```
var a = (new Boolean(false)) ? "unexpected" : "expected";
console.log(a); // unexpected
```

The question: is Boolean object an Object, or a Boolean? Should we not evaluate Boolean object as a Boolean?

---

***UPDATE***

My question was marked as duplicate question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript). That question doesn't have a satisfactory answers because none answers my question, **Is Boolean object an Object, or a Boolean? Should we not evaluate Boolean object as a Boolean?**

Simply knowing Boolean object is an object is not enough, why does it even exists and what is the proper way of dealing and/or designing objects with Boolean object still left unanswered.

Comment: Use `!Boolean(false)` which works as expected.

Comment: Why should Boolean (the object) be a boolean (the primitive data type) and not an Object? Boolean (the object) is an object representation of a boolean (the primitive data type).

Answer (score 32):

> An `object`, no matter if it has properties or not, never defaults to `false`[...](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Proxy_Pattern)

`new Boolean(true)` will return an `object` not `Boolean` and `!{}` is always going to be `false` as `{}` is a `truthy` value (`Boolean({})` will be evaluated as `true`)

While dealing with `Boolean` factory function, do not create new instance using `new` (as it will create new instance of `Boolean` and will return an `object`)

**`Boolean(INPUT)`** will return `primitive-Boolean` value of the specified `expression` which could be used for `comparison`

From docs, *The Boolean object is an object wrapper for a `boolean value`()*

> **Description:** *The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a `boolean` value, if necessary. If value is omitted or is `0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string ("")`, the object has an initial value of `false`. All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of `true`.*

**Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the true and false values of the Boolean object.**

*Any object whose value is not `undefined` or `null`, including a `Boolean object` whose value is false, evaluates to `true` **"when passed to a conditional statement."**[[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)]*

For example, the condition in the following if statement evaluates to `true`

```js
var x = new Boolean("false");
if (x) {
  console.log('x is true');
}

var y = new Boolean(false);
if (y) {
  console.log('y is true');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

`Boolean` is a function. Depending on the invocation type, it has different behavior in terms of `truthy` and `falsy`.

**1. Invoking as a simple function**

When calling `Boolean(value)` as a simple function, it verifies if the argument is a `falsy` (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `0`,`Nan`) or `truthy` (all other values: object instances, `1`, `true`, etc). This type of invocation returns a [boolean primitive type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).
It works as expected:

```
Boolean(null) // prints false
Boolean(0)    // prints false

Boolean({})  // prints true
Boolean(-1)  // prints true
```

**2. Invoking as a constructor**

Like any function in JavaScript, `Boolean` can be invoked as a constructor: `var b = new Boolean(value)`. This invocation type returns a [boolean object instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).
This introduces confusing because JavaScript treats object instances as `truthy` value.

```
var b = new Boolean(null);

!!b // prints true, because b is an object instance

if (b) { // b evaluates to true
   //executed code 
}
```

**2.1 Why invoking as a constructor is possible**

JavaScript allows this constructor invocation to give developer a mechanism to preserve properties creation for a `boolean`. A primitive boolean type doesn't save properties assigned to it.

```
var booleanObject = new Boolean(null);
booleanObject.foo = 'bar'; // create a property
booleanObject.foo // prints 'bar'

var booleanPrimitive = false;
booleanPrimitive.foo = 'bar'; // create a property
booleanPrimitive.foo // prints undefined
```

**2.2 How to make the Boolean object work**

Nevertheless, `new Boolean(value)` has a mechanism to do comparison. Like any JavaScript object, it has a method `valueOf()`, which returns the transformation of the `value` to a boolean primitive type (`true` for truthy and `false` for falsy):

```
var falsyBoolean = new Boolean(null);
falsyBoolean.valueOf() // prints false, because null is falsy

var truthyBoolean = new Boolean(1);
truthyBoolean.valueOf() // prints true, because 1 is truthy
```

To make this work in conditionals, it is necessary to avoid any transformations of the boolean object instance into a truthy value. To make this happen, use comparison operator `==` directly:

```
var falsyBoolean = new Boolean(null);

falsyBoolean == false ? 'falsy' : 'truthy' // prints expected 'falsy'

if (falsyBoolean == false) { 
  //executed code
}
```

If an operand in `==` operator is an object and other a primitive type, JavaScript transforms it into a primitive type, which actually consists in calling the `valueOf()` method on the boolean object. See more details in [this article](http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/).

**3. How not to get confused**

The best rule is to avoid using `Boolean` as object instances at all. `Boolean(value)` or `!!value` is enough to verify the variable truthy state.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN's entry on Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean):

> Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement.
>
> For example, the condition in the following if statement evaluates to true:
>
> ```
>   var x = new Boolean("false");
>   if (x) {
>     // this code is executed
>   }
>
>   var y = new Boolean(false);
>   if (y) {
>     // this code is also executed
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You will get same result for `true` and `false` parameters when using `new Boolean(...)`

> [Object-Oriented JavaScript Book, Stoyan Stefanov:](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript) 
>   You can convert any value to its Boolean equivalent using a double negation.
>   Understanding how any value converts to a Boolean is important. Most values
>   convert to true with the exception of the following, which convert to false
>
> **"" 
> null 
> undefined 
> 0 
> NaN 
> false**

So `!!{}`, `!!new Boolean(true)`, `!!new Boolean(false)` return always `true`

This condition (without double negation):

```
if (new Boolean(true) === true) {

    console.log('this string will never be printed');
}
```

returns `false`, because there are different types:

```
typeof new Boolean(true); // "object"
typeof true; // "boolean"
```

You have to compare them only by value to get an expected result:

```
if (new Boolean(true) == true) {

    console.log('Yay!');
}

new Boolean(true) == true; // true
new Boolean(true) === true; // false
```

Another example:

```
if (new Boolean(true) === new Boolean(true)) {

    console.log('this string will never be printed')
}
```

In this case you are trying to compare objects. You will get the same result both with `==` and `===` compare operators.

> [Object-Oriented JavaScript Book, Stoyan Stefanov:](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript) 
> When you compare objects, you'll get true only if you compare two
>   references to the same object. Comparing two distinct objects that
>   happen to have the exact same methods and properties returns false.

Do not use a Boolean object `new Boolean(...)` in place of a Boolean primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried out the folliwng:

```
            alert(typeof true);    //alerts boolean
            alert(typeof new Boolean(true));   //alert object
            alert(typeof !(new Boolean(true)));   //alerts boolean
            alert(!(new Boolean(true)));         //alerts false
```

Both Rayon and Mukul are right, you just need to use `!Boolean(false)` //returns true as a boolean value.