# JavaScript how is this if working while the value is false

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic

Could anyone explain me why it displays the alert dialog while the didSolve variable is false. @_@

```
            var didSolve = false;  

            $.get(
                "http://stardebris.net/solve-field.php",
                {id : "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" },
                function(data) 
                {
                      didSolve = true;
                }
            });           
            var img = new Image();
            var div = document.getElementById('image-gallery');

            img.onload = function() 
            {
                div.appendChild(img);
                $('.pannable-image').ImageViewer();
            };

            if (didSolve)
            {
                alert(didSolve);
                //TRUE
            }
            else
            {
                //FALSE
            }
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: true but false]

UPDATE: Added $get function as this might be causing my problem.

Comment: Because you use `Boolean` you are creating an object version of the `boolean` primitive. Objects are treated as truthy values.

Comment: It's doing it in my environment aswell. When I change `if (didSolve)` to `if (didSolve == true)` it seems to work however.

Comment: In a previous version of the code you had `var didSolve = new Boolean(0);`, and it was explained to you why that wouldn't work.

Now you have `var didSolve = false;` - are you saying you have tested the code again after making that change and you're still getting the same results?

Comment: @Tex yes but I updated that to match what I meant, I think it doesn't update the variable inside the get function. I fixed it though. I just moved the code inside the get function and then it does work :D

Comment: Yes, you have to move the code inside the `$get()` function because that's an asynchronous function. The way you had originally written it, all of the code after the `$get()` would have been executed before the `$get()` call finished.

Also, the way the code is now displayed is misleading, since I can guarantee that the alert won't say 'false' after you changed the code to use `var didSolve = false;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Boolean(0) == false; //equals to true
new Boolean(0) === false; //equals to false
```

`new Boolean(0)` is an object, not a simple boolean. i guess JS simply sucks that much that it doesn't cast it to a true "false".

Have you tried using

```
didSolve = false;
```

instead?

edit:
see also: [Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes when I do this it is false yes,
But then I cannot set it to true.

Is it possible that I cannot change the value of didSolve inside

$.get(
                    "URL",
                    {id : "1" },
                    function(data) 
                    { didSolve = true; });

Comment: then you could try comparing. `new Boolean(0) == false` equals true and `new boolean(0) == true` equals false.

Comment: Better would be to not use `new Boolean(0)`. `Boolean(0)` without the `new` will work as he expects.

Comment: Im used to C++ which seems to be less difficult with booleans :P

Answer (score 1):

Lint your code - you should not be using `Boolean` as a constructor.

`var thing = new Boolean(0) // won't work like you expect.`

`var thing = Boolean(0) // will work like you expect.`

jsLint will warn you if you use [`Boolean` as a constructor](https://jslinterrors.com/do-not-use-a-as-a-constructor).

MDN clearly says, "[do not use a Boolean object in place of a Boolean primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)."