# Accessing a boolean property of an object in javascript always returns false?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm losing my mind. I have an array of objects called `allAvailabilities`

```
console.log(allAvailabilities[0]);
```

results in a object with various properties, one of which is:

```
...
isTrainee: true
...
```

but

```
console.log(allAvailabilities[0]['isTrainee']);
console.log(allAvailabilities[0].isTrainee);
```

results in

```
false
false
```

I'm not understanding what is preventing me from accessing the actual `isTrainee` value of the object property:

```
console.log(typeof(allAvailabilities[0]['isTrainee']));
console.log(typeof(allAvailabilities[0].isTrainee));
console.log(allAvailabilities[0]['isTrainee'].toString());
console.log(allAvailabilities[0].isTrainee.toString());
```

results in:

```
boolean
boolean
false
false
```

How is this possible? Am I overlooking a fundamental piece of Javascript syntax? Does this have to do with the `Boolean` class as described here:
[Why does !new Boolean(false) equals false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695341/why-does-new-booleanfalse-equals-false-in-javascript)

[image]

The snippet works fine, what does this mean?

```js
var allAvailabilities = [{_id: '605a5dd76f007e84f28e35fd', begin: '2021-04-03T18:00:00.000Z', end: '2021-04-03T20:30:00.000Z', season: 'regular', hostModel: 'users', isTrainee: true, season: "regular"}];


            console.log(allAvailabilities[0]);
            console.log(typeof(allAvailabilities[0]['isTrainee']));
            console.log(typeof(allAvailabilities[0].isTrainee));
            console.log(allAvailabilities[0]['isTrainee'].toString());
            console.log(allAvailabilities[0].isTrainee.toString());
```

How can this be?
[image]

The original `allAvailabilities` array comes from an API, and each object in the array is modified to have the `isTrainee` property like so, immediately before calling the code I am having problems with:

[image]

Comment: Please make this reproducible. Include a runnable snippet (using toolbar in editor) that illustrates this behaviour, so we can see it. It is likely you were looking at a different object (in the same array) when you saw that the property was true instead of false.

Comment: Another possibility is that your array is being mutated by the rest of your code, but after your `console.log`. In that case the console will show the later content of the objects, not at the time of the `console.log`. See [is console.log lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects)

Comment: @trincot I have added a snippet using the exact same code, and the snippet works as expected. Checking the lazy console.log post now.

Comment: I confirm it is the lazy stuff, because in your screenshot (which should not be an image! please post as text), it is clear the subscribe callback code is executed *after* you do the `console.log`.

Comment: Move all your code that depends on the processing you do in the `subscribe` callback, inside that callback (or call a function there, or chain a listener,...etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because there is a promise asynchronous modification of *isTrainee* in the map. I think changing the map to for may solve the problem. For is a synchronous function rather than asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited my original post to show the modification of the array immediately before the problem print statements.

Comment: Hey Alex, your message is more of a comment than an answer I think. Please think about what you should post and have a look at the guidelines

Comment: @Asa Please see if the compiled answer is helpful to you

Comment: No, changing the `map` to a `for` will not solve the problem.