# status.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

The browser’s console says:

> ```
> TypeError: status.style is undefined, line 12
> ```

```
var status;
function output(msg,type="info"){
    status.innerHTML=msg;
    switch(type){
        case "info":
            status.style.background=undefined;
            break;
        case "warning":
            status.style.background="#cccc33";
            break;
        case "error":
            status.style.background="#ff0033";
            break;
    }
}
function init(){
    status=document.getElementById("status");
    output("Document loaded","error");
}
window.onload=init;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
        <title>Drag and drop upload</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Drag & drop upload</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="status">Status</div>
            <div id="inner"> </div>
        </div>
        <footer>&copy; Copyright 2015</footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

I know this is so simple and basic but I got no other choice but to ask. As I tested I think this is a scope error. So what’s the problem?

Comment: Is this Javascript before or after the HTML is declared? Sometimes, if you call a DOM object before the page is finished, it doesn't declare.

Comment: I get it. Don’t use `status`…

Comment: thanks  Xufox its worked.but why it happened?

Comment: Consider using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for questions and answers involving JS, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: @SomeOne I posted an answer. That’s a very subtle thing that you stumbled upon…

Comment: @SomeOne I strongly encourage you to use [JSHint.com](http://jshint.com) to validate your JavaScript code in the future. It actually says “Redefinition of `status`.” and “Read only.”; JSHint is a great tool!

Comment: @SomeOne I updated my answer because of two things: there’s another solution to your problem which allows you to use the same variable names and I incorrectly assumed that the weirdness of `window.status` was based on getters and setters — instead it’s based on WebIDL bindings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`var status = true\` can't be set as boolean, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788709/var-status-true-cant-be-set-as-boolean-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not actually referring to your `status` variable, but to `window.status`.

There are two possible solutions to this:

- Simply don’t use `status`, but another variable name instead, or
- Wrap your code in an IIFE like this: `(function(){…}());`

---

`window.status` is a special property: it has a WebIDL binding. In this case, this basically means that the value of the property is changed and updated secretly. In the case of `window.status`, whenever a value is assigned to it, it is turned into a string. That’s why `console.log(status)` yields the string

```
"[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

instead of the *element*

```
<div id="status">
```

And only HTML elements have the `style` property, not strings. That’s why `status.style` is `undefined`.

That’s not an issue if you access an undefined property of a defined value. That’s why `status.innerHTML` didn’t throw the error. But with `status.style.background`, you tried to access an undefined property of an *undefined* value.

If you use immediately invokable function expressions (IIFEs), you can use whichever variable names you want:

```
(function(){
  var status;
  // etc.
})();
```

---

[`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/status) was used to set the status text of a window (back then, when browsers had status bars).

Comment: because you are setting a property of the object, not a bug. When you try to read a property that does not exists of an object it has an issue.