# How does one detect a null result from name = prompt() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null

Consider this code:

```js
var name = prompt("What is your name", "Anonymous");
if (name == null) {
  alert("detected null");
  name = "Anonymous";
}
alert("Hello " + name);
```

It is my understanding that clicking [Cancel] or pressing the [Escape] key will cause the JavaScript `window.prompt(text, [default])` function to return `null` (or perhaps `undefined` in older versions of IE)

When I execute the above code in Firefox, the expected prompt appears.  However, when I press [Escape], I never see the "detected null" message (and the name variable is not set to "Anonymous". It is as if the `name` variable is not being set to `null`.  Interestingly, the last alert displays "Hello null".

I've tried swapping out the `name == null` check with `name === null` with the same behavior.

How does one detect `null` in JavaScript?

Please note: I am really trying to detect null, not an empty string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript

Comment: The return value of `prompt` seems to always be a string. If you press the escape key, you’ll get the _string_ `"null"`.

Comment: @Sulthan He already is using `name == null`, which should match both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @Xufox, I have not tested your claim yet. But if it is true, how does one distinguish between the user pressing [Escape] / clicking [Cancel] and a user who actually entered the string "null" as their input?

Comment: @digitale I’ve just logged the ouput to the console to see what the actual return value is. The fact that you can’t distinguish the two options for `"null"` is why I haven’t posted an answer, but only a comment… I don’t know either…

Comment: I think this is **not** a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript. The main difference is that in this case the null value is produced by a prompt function, and I didn't know that to check if I have pressed 'cancel' I have to compare the value with "null". So in this case there is not a null value, It's a string with the "null" value..

Comment: `x == null` checks for `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the variable “name” doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523701/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `prompt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns `null` when the user presses escape, [as described in the *Web application APIs* section of the latest HTML 5 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20151008/webappapis.html#dom-prompt):

> 7. If the user aborts, then return null; otherwise, return the string that the user responded with.

You just need to check that `result === null` or `result == null`, as you have done.

The behaviour you're encountering doesn't have to do with `prompt()`. It's because you're trying to use the variable `name` in a global scope. You aren't actually declaring a new variable. You're reusing [the global `window.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), which is automatically converted to a string:

```js
var nameNumber = 21;
var name = 21;
document.write([typeof nameNumber, typeof name]);  // number,string
```

Your code will work correctly if you use a different variable name, or if you wrap it in a function so it isn't colliding with the global variable.

```js
function main() {
  var name = prompt("What is your name", "Anonymous");
  if (name == null) {
    alert("detected null");
    name = "Anonymous";
  }
  alert("Hello " + name);
} 

main();
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for mentioning the existence of the global variable, "name".

Comment: So this is the same issue as in [status.style is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31753711/4642212). Why haven’t I seen this immediately?!