# JavaScript: Login/Register with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Hey there I know it's probably an easy question but I've a problem with my Login/Register in JavaScript. I'm storing the users data via localStorage and when I try to login he always returns my alert message, that the typed in data is wrong.

EDIT: storedName is undefined but password isn't. I still don't get it..

EDIT: Problem solved. Thanks to Hank! Solution is in the comments.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning JavaScript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="register-form"> 
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value=""/>
            <input id="pw" type="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
            <input id="rgstr_btn" type="submit" value="get Account" onClick="store()"/> 
        </form>

        <form id="login-form"> 
            <input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value=""/>
            <input id="userPw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value=""/>
            <input id="login_btn" type="submit" value="Login" onClick="check()"/> 
       </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
// Name and Password from the register-form
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var pw = document.getElementById('pw');

// storing input from register-form
function store() {
    localStorage.setItem('name', name.value);
    localStorage.setItem('pw', pw.value);
}

// check if stored data from register-form is equal to entered data in the   login-form
function check() {

    // stored data from the register-form
    var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var storedPw = localStorage.getItem('pw');

    // entered data from the login-form
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
    var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');

    // check if stored data from register-form is equal to data from login form
    if(userName.value !== storedName || userPw.value !== storedPw) {
        alert('ERROR');
    }else {
        alert('You are loged in.');
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I checked the console storedName is undefined but he gets the password

Comment: [Another question about the global `name` variable collision causing weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33963203/1114).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have 2 issues:
1. "name" is a reserved word, it's gonna act goffy on you, change it to something else like name1 or nm or something.
2. don't use !==, != will do, you logic is faulty anyways, change it to this:

```
if(userName.value == storedName && userPw.value == storedPw) {
        alert('You are loged in.');
    }else {
        alert('ERROR.');
    }
```

But yeah, I know you are just practicing, but don't actually save usernames and passwords on the client side.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Just one question if you read this. Why didn't it work with !== ? And how would you otherwise store userdata in JavaScript?

Comment: Glad it worked for you!     
 
!== is more strict than !=, you can only use !== (or ===) on properties of the exact same types, to me, most of the time, it's just an overkill to be so strict unless you are actually checking the type of a specific property, e.g. 
 
 if(typeof someImg !== "undefined")
 {
  //this property someImg is actually a thing
 }
  
You generally wanna store user names and passwords in the database with encryption.

Comment: This is why it did not work .. that makes sence .. thanks that you answered. And yes, I know that I should've stored it in a database. Actually I do it with PHP but for some reason my teacher wanted me to search for an option, to store data in JS and "localStorage" was the only thing I found by far. Anyways I wish ya a good evening

Answer (score 1):

```
// entered data from the login-form
var userName=document.getElementById('userName');
var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');
```

This is where the issue came to you. 
You wanted to compare the entered values with the `localStorage` data. This is good but it should have been like this:

```
var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw').value;
```

This is the correct way to get the value of the input field.

Comment: // entered data from the login-form
var userName=document.getElementById('userName');
var userPw=document.getElementById('userPw');

This is where the issue came to you. 
You wanted to compare the entered values with the  localstorege data. This is good but you omitted this snippet.   .value

It should have been like this
    
 var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw').value;

This is the correct way to get the value of the input field.

Comment: This was not the issue; the value was properly accessed every time it was meant to be used. The question-asker already confirmed that @Hank;s solution worked, over two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>logSign</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" required>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" required>
    <input id="signup_btn" type="submit" value="Signup">
  </form>

  <form id="login-form">
    <input id="name2" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" required>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" required>
    <input id="login_btn" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#signup-form").submit(function () {
        var nm1 = $("#name1").val();
        var ps1 = $("#pass1").val();
        localStorage.setItem("n1", nm1);
        localStorage.setItem("p1", ps1);

      });

      $("#login-form").submit(function () {
        var enteredName = $("#name2").val();
        var enteredPass = $("#pass2").val();

        var storedName = localStorage.getItem("n1");
        var storedPass = localStorage.getItem("p1");

        if (enteredName == storedName && enteredPass == storedPass) {
          alert("You are logged in!");
        }
        else {
          alert("Username and Password do not match!");
        }

      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```