# Can't store a boolean returned by a function in a variable

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this is a bug, but it feels kind of strange. Can you store a boolean returned by a function in a variable using javascript? Whenever I try to store a boolean value in a variable which is returned by a function, it gets changed to string.

I have the following function which converts a string to a boolean

```
function str2bool(strvalue){
  console.log("Value is - " + strvalue);
  console.log("Type is - " + typeof strvalue);
  return (strvalue && typeof strvalue == 'string') ? (strvalue.toLowerCase() == 'true') : (strvalue == true);
}
```

> I've found this function somewhere here on StackOverflow, but I do not remember it's author, so if you are reading this, sorry about me not giving proper credits:)

I have another javascript line, which looks as follows:

```
target.prop('disabled',str2bool(booleanInStringFormat));
console.log("Typeof str2bool return is - " + typeof str2bool(booleanInStringFormat));
```

If I use it this way, everyting works fine, the str2bool function returns the following lines to the console:

> Value is - false
>   
>  Type is - string

And the line after the main function returns:

> Typeof of str2bool function is - boolean

But if I try to store the return value of str2bool in a variable, and use it afterwards, the prop function won't work, because apparently the variable that I use to store the return value of str2bool becomes a string. If I run this code I get the following results:

```
status = str2bool(booleanInStringFormat);
console.log("Typeof status is - " + typeof status);
target.prop('disabled',status);
```

The results are the following:

> Value is - false
>   
>  Type is - string
>   Typeof status is - string
>   
> End result is that target remains disabled

So, why is the typeof the variable in which I store the return of the function is changed back to string?

Comment: Yep, that’s implicit string conversion. _Something_ `+` _String_ `==` _String_. Always (well most of the time).

Comment: But nothing is being added to the end result...

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood it… whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use global variable `status`, which appeared to be a property of the global object `window`, this property could only be **string**.

The **[window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)**.

You could just change to an other variable name, but much better, avoid using global variable.

```
(function(){
  var status = str2bool('false');
  console.log(typeof status);
}());
```

Comment: Yep, this was the problem... thanks for the prompt answer!:) What is the global status variable for btw? Thanks:) Will mark this as correct in a few minutes:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai It is used to set the text in the status bar at the bottom of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the below snippet, it seems we can return a boolean and save it

```
function booleanReturnCheck(){
   return false;
}

var isBool = booleanReturnCheck();
console.log(isBool);
console.log(typeof (isBool));
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ppruqcu5/2/)

Comment: Yes, the problem was the variable in which I tried to store it:) See below answer:) Thanks for the effort though:)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer on this link discusses boolean variables.  Maybe something there might help: [Declaring a boolean in JavaScript using just var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653921/declaring-a-boolean-in-javascript-using-just-var)

The section to pay attention to is

```
var IsLoggedIn1 = "true"; //string
var IsLoggedIn2 = 1; //integer
var IsLoggedIn3 = true; //bool
```

It seems that your values are strings because they are being set as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse bool using `!!`

```
var bool = !!'true';
```

Comment: That must mean that `!!'false'` returns `false`, _right_?

Comment: The thing is: it doesn’t work that way. Any string that isn’t empty is considered `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a Boolean Variable using :

1. `var myVar = Boolean("false");`
2. `var myVar = !!"false";`

Note that any string which isn't the empty string or "false" will evaluate to "true".